# Looking for GPS system for delivering

Tags: android, ios, gps

I am looking for a GPS system that does the following:

- Can see live traffic
- Can save frequent route that the driver travels to weekly
- Can plan the most effective route if there are multiple destinations
- On site personnel can upload the route directly to the driver's GPS (could be an actually GPS or an app on iOS/android)
- Can estimate the time before the driver is back at the shop so that on site personnel can plan emergency additional destinations or change of destinations if needed (would be able to notify the driver's gps and update to new destinations).

The system I'm looking for can be free, open source or paid.  Any help is appreciated!